VS Code not selecting correct conda environment for py but works for ipynb
I have a workspace with a .py and a .ipynb file. After I've selected the correct conda environment (py39llm ) VS Code keeps working with the base conda environment in the case of .py but switches to the selected python environment for ipynb:
Executing the following:
import os
bashCommand = "conda info --env"
os.system(bashCommand)

on the .ipynb:
# conda environments:
#
base                     /home/fes33/anaconda3
py39llm               *  /home/fes33/anaconda3/envs/py39llm

on the .py:
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/fes33/anaconda3
py39llm                  /home/fes33/anaconda3/envs/py39llm

Even though as the bar at the bottom shows I've selected the correct environment:


If you set "python.defaultInterpreterPath" in your User settings.json, will it work?

In jupyter, you need to select kernel in the top right corner.

Next, select a kernel using the kernel picker in the top right.


https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_create-or-open-a-jupyter-notebook

Jupyter works fine. My problem is with the standard python script.
